# Is it possible to use NewRelic with hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: newrelic

I have an Android mobile app but it is an hybrid mobile up using phonegap.

I have installed NewRelic and configured everything as explained in the video / instructions.

When I start using the application NewRelic detect the application but it only traces the number of active sessions, nothing else.

The application makes the http requests using ajax, not any Android java code.

All the other information is gather from http requests done used Android java code? or is it possible to gather information in case the app is an hybrid app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for non-native apps varies a bit by framework: there's a New Relic module for Titanium, but support for Phonegap is more limited currently. The New Relic for Mobile Apps iOS SDK can instrument the iOS version of your app, but currently the Android version of a Phonegap app will show up just as you describe it: monitoring active users but not web requests.